# Convert dojo function in jquery

Tags: .net

I have to convert below dojo in jquery. This function works fine form my html code but I need this to be converted in jquery as per the requirement. Is there any easy way for this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        dojo.require("dojo.parser");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
        dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");

        dojo.ready(function () {
            dojo.declare(
                    "FilterSelectReadStore",
                    dojox.data.QueryReadStore,
                    {
                        fetch: function (request) {

                            request.serverQuery = { method: 'search', q: request.query.SearchTerm, db: 'brimbank' };
                            // Call superclasses' fetch
                            return this.inherited("fetch", arguments);
                        }
                    }
                );

            //Parse the html elements for dojo
            dojo.parser.parse();
        });
    </script>
```